# Statistics/ Regression on Excel

Tags: excel, statistics

I am working on a project to determine how much our online campaigns of sales of clothing items will generate. These are periodic campaigns that run for 5 days in different times of the year and I want to be able to build a model that predicts how much money each of those campaigns might generate. I am using Excel and I basically developed a multiple regression model that works like:

Turnover = Constant + (a * Number of units) + (b * Type of Stock) + (c * Time of the Year) + (d * Selling Price)

I get an adjusted R-square of 0.44 and I know the reason for that is because the most important variable isn't being taken into consideration - the brand name. A campaign with "Nike" will perform much better than a campaign of "Bob's Sports Shoes".

So my question is - using Excel, how can I:

- Introduce this variable into my regression? As I can't code all the names into dummy variables should I just cluster the campaign names by intervals of historic turnover? (e.g.: I could have a cluster "5" for Nike, Adidas, etc., a cluster 4, 3, 2, and then "Bob's Sports Shoes" and the others could be cluster 1)
- Is there any other approach that I can use in Excel instead of multiple regression to get to a better model?

Thanks!!!

Comment: How does using `Type of Stock` as a numerical variable make any sense? That is as categorical as `brand name`.

Comment: By the way, why can't you code all the names into dummy variables? If it is simply because there are too many then your idea of grouping them into categories certainly makes sense although there is the danger that your clustering into categories will be somewhat arbitrary. It seems like you might have more of a machine learning problem rather than anything which can be handled by anything as simple as a regression model (time of year also seems somewhat disparate in meaning from the other variables). Maybe train a neural net (using VBA).

Comment: There are only 2 types of stock - so I coded one as 0 and the other as 1. Not being able to code all the names into dummy variables is indeed because of the sheer number of brands (at least several hundreds).

Comment: Consider deleting the question on Stack Overflow and posting it here instead: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ . It really isn't an Excel question so much as a statistical methodology question. Over at that site you would probably get a more informed answer about how to combine numerical and categorical predictor variables when there are too many levels to use dummy variables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!